# One regex for all class in package and another regex for the one class inside the same package with Log4j2 configuration

Tags: java, regex, log4j, log4j2

Following project structure is present in java application with log4j2 xml configuration .

**com.app.package.one**

- class1.java
- class2.java
- class3.java
- class4.java

**com.app.package.two**

- class5.java
- class6.java
- class7.java
- class8.java

whole application to print the loggers on following **all three conditions to be matched**

condition1-> print the error mode logger for all the classes

condition2-> print if the logging statement has "exception" in part of logging statement

condition3-> for package 2's class 7 alone it needs exclusion that to display if the logging statement contains exception or sometext

i have added the following log4j2 xml configuration which is satisfying the condition1 and condition2 . but cannot able to achieve the condition 3 in the same configuration .

working configuration for condition 1 and 2

```
<Logger name="com.app.package" level="error">
<RegexFilter regex=".*(?i)exception(?-i).*" onMatch="ACCEPT" onMismatch="DENY"/>
</Logger>
```

not working for condition 3

```
<Logger name="com.app.package" level="error">
     <RegexFilter regex=".*(?i)exception(?-i).*" onMatch="ACCEPT" onMismatch="DENY"/>
</Logger>

<Logger name="com.app.package.two.class7" level="error">
     <RegexFilter regex=".*(?i)exception(?-i).* | .*(?i)sometext(?-i).*" onMatch="ACCEPT" onMismatch="DENY"/>
</Logger>
```

is this possible to do a package level filter and as well class level filter both at a time for same class ?

any input on this will be help full,

thanks in advance... :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For condition 3

there were two problem on the logging configuration

1)appender information to be added

2)on regex space before and after pipe | symbol

the altered configuration working for all there condition is looks below

```
<Logger name="com.app.package" level="error">
<RegexFilter regex=".*(?i)exception(?-i).*" onMatch="ACCEPT" onMismatch="DENY"/>
<AppenderRef ref="LogToConsole"/>  
</Logger>
<Logger name="com.app.package.two.class7" level="error">
 <RegexFilter regex=".*(?i)exception(?-i).*|.*(?i)sometext(?-i).*" onMatch="ACCEPT" onMismatch="DENY"/>
<AppenderRef ref="LogToConsole"/>
</Logger>
```